# Toggle text display using pure CSS :hover pseudo-class

Tags: css

I want the text to change completely when someone hovers over it. I found code online that should work, but it doesn't. Any suggestions?

```
<span class="show">
     <p>if {&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>yourSite < awesome;&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>solution = aislingDouglas (HTML5 + CSS3 +&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>JavaScript + PHP);&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>}&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>else {&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>solution = null;&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>}&nbsp;</p>
 </span>

 <span class="noshow">
     <p>Need a website? &nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>You found your dream developer!&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>And hey - I already helped you on the web,&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>why not let me help you&nbsp;<br /></p>
     <p>build an amazing site!&nbsp;<br /></p>
 </span>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.noshow, p:hover .show { display: none }
p:hover .noshow { display: inline }
```

I'm not opposed to using JavaScript (coding suggestions welcome), but I'd prefer it to stay in CSS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<p>` is not a valid child of `<span>`.

Comment: should use `&lt;` in place of < in `<p>yourSite < awesome;&nbsp;<br /></p>`

Comment: Sorry, is **[this what you are looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/Mee3/pAgGT/)**

Comment: Could you give the link to where online you found it? It might help.

Comment: Please provide a JSfiddle link for testing

Comment: I originally found it here: http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/576913-change-text-on-hover-css/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="show">
        <p>if {&nbsp;</p>
        <p>yourSite
            < awesome;&nbsp; </p>
                <p>solution = aislingDouglas (HTML5 + CSS3 +&nbsp;</p>
                <p>JavaScript + PHP);&nbsp;</p>
                <p>}&nbsp;</p>
                <p>else {&nbsp;</p>
                <p>solution = null;&nbsp;</p>
                <p>}&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="noshow">
        <p>Need a website? &nbsp;</p>
        <p>You found your dream developer!&nbsp;</p>
        <p>And hey - I already helped you on the web,&nbsp;</p>
        <p>why not let me help you&nbsp;</p>
        <p>build an amazing site!&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.wrap {
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    height: 300px;
}
.noshow, .wrap:hover .show {
    display: none
}
.wrap:hover .noshow {
    display: block
}
```

You need an outer container to wrap the two blocks that will be toggled on and off.

For best results, set a height to the outer wrapper or else you can get a oscillating show/hide effect since the panel will resize itself due to the different amount of text, which means that that the mouse may not be over the panel about to be displayed, so the hover state will be instantly reverted to not-hover, hence re-triggering the show/hide effect.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/zAt7f/

Comment: @ummlayth You are very welcome! This is a good technique to know.  Please up vote a couple of these answers since they both good solutions to the problem.

Comment: Sweet! Just got to 15 so I can finally upvote - upvote done! Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You've got the right idea, sort of...

The goal is to have a container element which holds both sections of text. 
When that element is moused over it gets assigned the pseudoclass `:hover`. Using this selector, you can re-style the children (below, `.first` and `.second`) appropriately.

Note that I've used `<span>` for the text and `<p>` for the parent below, but if you want to do this with **block level** children like more `<p>` elements, then you should use `<div>` as the parent instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/G28qz/

HTML:

```
<p class="hovertext">
    <span class="first">This is what you see first</span>
    <span class="second">But this shows up on mousehover</span>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
/* Hide the second piece of text by default */
p.hovertext .second {
     display:none;
}

/* Hide the first piece of text on hover */
p.hovertext:hover .first {
     display:none;
}

/* Re-show the second piece of text on hover */
p.hovertext:hover .second {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thanks for taking the time out to answer - it really helped!